# Aggregate Data Source New Form Field Problem

Tags: column, form, data

I have webpart with five form field. But i need a data from another list. So i use linked data source. When i use it my all form fields broken.Some Input type text change input type file.

```
<DataSources>
    <SharePoint:AggregateDataSource runat="server" IsSynchronous="false" id="aggregatedatasource1" SeparateRoot="True"><sources>
            <SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" UseServerDataFormat="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;/View&gt;">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{5DCD41B0-CC9B-41A2-AD73-84231CD759C8}"/>
                </SelectParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{5DCD41B0-CC9B-41A2-AD73-84231CD759C8}"/>
                </InsertParameters>
            </SharePoint:SPDataSource>
            <SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" UseServerDataFormat="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;/View&gt;">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="{BBCC0A9A-C56D-4C24-ADBC-CFD5042CC875}"/>
                </SelectParameters>
            </SharePoint:SPDataSource>
        </sources><aggregate>
            <concat name="data source">
                <datasource name="Web_İstek" id="0" Type="SPList"/>
                <datasource name="EtkinlikTakvimi" id="1" Type="SPList"/>
            </concat>
        </aggregate>
    </SharePoint:AggregateDataSource>

</DataSources>
```